# compare date string in php with mm-dd-yy format

Tags: php, date, datetime, compare

i need to compare two date from string, 
my dates: 
first date: 11-11-19 
second date: 11-24-17

so i try to

```
$firstdate = "11-11-19";
$seconddate = "11-24-17";

if($firstdate < $seconddate)
    {
        echo "firstdate is minor than the secondate";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "seconddate is major than the firstdate";
    }
```

if i change < or > the if statement should change, but i get always the firsdate...
how to do to compare two dates in this forma mm-dd-yy ?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert string to unix timestamp, and compare that.

```php
$firstdate = strtotime("11-11-19");
$seconddate = strtotime("11-24-17");

if($firstdate < $seconddate)
    {
        echo "firstdate is minor than the secondate";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "seconddate is major than the firstdate";
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can convert both dates to timestamp:

```
echo (strtotime($firstdate) < strtotime($seconddate)) ? "firstdate is minor than the secondate" : "seconddate is major than the firstdate";
```

Comment: I am sure it is not intentional, but this is the same answer what I posted before. :)